# Installing mysqlnd_qc plugin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, plugins, mysqlnd

I need to install the `mysqlnd_qc` plugin.

So, what I achieved yet is installing `MySQL Native Driver`, `Apache`.. etc. and that's all.

How I tried to install? With `PECL`, using this `pecl install mysqlnd_qc-1.2.0.tar` command in terminal.

But compilation failed.

```
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_qc/php_mysqlnd_qc.c:32:0:
/tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_qc/mysqlnd_qc.h:38:40: fatal error: 
ext/standard/php_smart_str.h: No such file or directory #include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"
                                  ^   compilation terminated.
```

My server details are here:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
PHP 5.6.38-2+0~20181015120829.6+stretch~1.gbp567807 (cli)
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

If you need more details, please, feel free to ask me.

UPDATE: I have tried to compile even with the source code, I am getting the same error.
In the INSTALL file it is specified that I need to have PHP-src. Why? Doesn't PHP have the files?